# How dynamically change images in SurfaceView?

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I am using default SurfaceView implementation, code can be found [here](https://github.com/vivekrk/SurfaceView-Sample)(this is a finger drawing app example, I just disabled that and drawn an image). There are 3 main **separate** classes -

1. An Activity Class (**SurfaceViewSampleActivity**)
2. SurfaceView (**CanvasView**)
3. Thread class (**UIThread**).

SurfaceView draws image(Bitmap) which is set in constructor. I also implemented functionality where user can call Camera app and take a picture. **Picture has to swap default image (on SurfaceView constructor set image).**

I tried to create a simple method in my activity class and set the bitmap, but this didn't work:

```
private void setImage() {
    view.bitmap = this.mImageBitmap; 

}
```

I thought that SurfaceView thread could be using bitmap so I tried to lock the variable:

```
private void setImage() {   
    synchronized (view.bitmap) {
        view.bitmap = this.mImageBitmap;
    }   
}
```

App also crashes.

SurfaceView draw method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    setPaintProperties();

    if (canvas != null) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        synchronized ( this.bitmap ) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, 0, 0, new Paint() );
        }

    }
}
```

Is there any way to change the bitmap variable in SurfaceView **after** the constructor has been called?

Comment: try without  synchronized ( this.bitmap )

Comment: Crashes... Thanks for quick responce

Comment: Please post the crash stacktrace from Logcat.

Answer (score 1):

What does your run method look like. I would take a look at the Lunar Lander sample. You need to lock and unlock the canvas.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mRun) {
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                    if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING) updatePhysics();
                    doDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```